# Default Windows 10 64 EFI partitions / partitioning scheme

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, uefi, efi

Sometimes you need to partition your disk which already contains a different operating system (OS) or version of Windows thus you use Linux tools such as `fdisk` or `gdisk` to create/configure partitions for adding Windows 10.

The question becomes which partitions 64bit Windows 10 running on UEFI/EFI requires.

Answer (score -1):

### fdisk

This doesn't list extra flags/attributes, see below.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 268435456 sectors
Disk model:
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: RANDOM_DISK_UUID

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 267387532 267147917 127.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  267388928 268431359   1042432   509M Windows recovery environment
```

### gdisk

```
Disk /dev/sda: 268435456 sectors, 128.0 GiB
Model:
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): RANDOM_DISK_UUID
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 268435422
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 7472 sectors (3.6 MiB)

Number  Start sector End sector  Size       Code  Name                        Flags
   1            2048     206847  100.0 MiB  EF00  EFI system partition        8000000000000000
   2          206848     239615  16.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved partion  8000000000000000
   3          239616  267387532  127.4 GiB  0700  Basic data partition        0000000000000000
   4       267388928  268431359  509.0 MiB  2700  Windows RE                  8000000000000001
```

### sfdisk

Also works as a script input for `fdisk`.

```
label: gpt
label-id: RANDOM_DISK_UUID
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 268435422
sector-size: 512

/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=      204800, type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, uuid=RANDOM_PART_UUID, name="EFI system partition", attrs="GUID:63"
/dev/sda2 : start=      206848, size=       32768, type=E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE, uuid=RANDOM_PART_UUID, name="Microsoft reserved partition", attrs="GUID:63"
/dev/sda3 : start=      239616, size=   267147917, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=RANDOM_PART_UUID, name="Basic data partition"
/dev/sda4 : start=   267388928, size=     1042432, type=DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC, uuid=RANDOM_PART_UUID, attrs="RequiredPartition GUID:63"
```

## PS

For some reasons Windows needs the RE partition as the last partition on the disk because Windows updates [may] increase its size and I've seen recommendations that it needs to be even larger than what you see here, 600MB to 1GB.